# What is the right approach to process a Freemarker Template on the fly in Spring service bean?

Tags: spring, templates, freemarker

I a few existing freemarker templates (ftl) in Spring MVC project. They are using standard spring tags (@spring.url, @spring.message and @spring.bind). While using standard approach of using FreemarkerConfig inside the servlet context (with ViewResolver) all of the templates work fine.

I also have some email templates which is programatically being created, but they are not using any spring tags or additional tlds.

The twist is, I have a task to use the regular template and process them using Freemarker Template class from a Service Bean. The service class have the find the template in the specified location ("/WEB-INF/views"), but it does not process the spring tags, and finds "spring" variable to null. I have set "auto_import" to "/spring.ftl as spring", but my understanding is it will only work within Web/servlet context? Am I using the right approach here? What is the best way to process a "Template" outside and how to expose the spring.tld or anyother.ltd for it? Appreciate your help / pointers!

Comment: Yes, `spring.ftl` needs the `springMacroRequestContext` variable, which is a `org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestContext` instance, and to create a `RequestContext` you need to provide a `HttpServletRequest` to the constructor... Certainly you can get away with a dummy `HttpServletRequest` for some spring macros, but who knows what will break when you upgrade Spring later.

Comment: Ok, I have done that and it works! Thanks for that tip, it would be nice to understand why "springMacroRequestContext" is switched off by default?

Comment: Spring adds `springMacroRequestContext` when you are generating a HTTP response for a HTTP request, and `springMacroRequestContext` might access the HTTP request and response sometimes. When sending e-mails, there's no HTTP request. Sure, in a very simple application maybe there happens to be one (until you refactor mail sending into an asynchronous background process), but you still don't generate a HTTP response there.